# Connecting pairs of dots on the scatterplot with jitter with lines - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two groups of points, but they also overlap, so I need to add jitter if I plot them with a scatterplot. I also want to connect matching points from each group (they all have a pair).

There are many questions that suggest:

```
data = [['abc', 'pre', 10], ['abc', 'post', 5], ['bce', 'pre', 10], ['bce', 'post', 5], ['cef', 'pre', 8], ['cef', 'post', 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'time', 'value'])
grouped = df.groupby('ID')

for name, group in grouped:
    sns.scatterplot(x='time', y='value', data=group, color='#3C74BC')
    sns.lineplot(x='time', y='value', data=group, color='#3C74BC')
plt.show()
```

It works ok, but it doesn't have jitter. If I add jitter via `sns. stripplot()`, the lines do not connect dots anymore and they are coming out of arbitrary places.

Comment: That was a mistake in the question. I don't have it in my actual code. I've added a test dataset. it's a bit problematic to add scatter manually because it's categorical at the moment, but I'll try to change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach below makes following changes:

- Convert the time to numeric (0 for 'pre' and 1 for 'post') via `(df['time'] != 'pre').astype(float)`
- Add a random jitter to these values: `+ np.random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1, len(df))`.  Depending on how many values you have, you might change `0.1` to a larger value.
- Use `sns.lineplot` with a marker to avoid the need of `scatterplot`.
- Use `hue='ID'` to draw everything in one go.
- As `hue` doesn't look to `color=`, use `palette=` with the same number of colors as there are different hue values.
- Suppress the legend, as all hue values have the same color.
- Assign tick labels to 0 and 1.
- Set `xlim` to so the tick labels are at equal distances to the respective border.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = [['abc', 'pre', 10], ['abc', 'post', 5], ['bce', 'pre', 10], ['bce', 'post', 5], ['cef', 'pre', 8], ['cef', 'post', 5]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ID', 'time', 'value'])

df['time'] = (df['time'] != 'pre').astype(float) + np.random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1, len(df))

ax = sns.lineplot(x='time', y='value', data=df, hue='ID', marker='o',
                  palette=['#3C74BC'] * len(df['ID'].unique()), legend=False)
ax.set_xticks([0, 1], ['pre', 'post'])
ax.set_xlim(-0.2, 1.2)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.lineplot with jitter]